# Config IIS for serving static files / CDN?

Tags: iis

Is there anyway to config IIS to serve static file like CDN? Like Gzip, Cache, E-tag, Mod-date?

And how should we config to make it very robust on massive requests?

I know it's a short question but that's all I want to ask.

---

To the question on the IIS version, i prefer 6 and 7 IIS. You can give your answer on either 6 or 7 :)

Thanks! I hope people find this question useful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Galcho has a post on [IIS7: How to set cache control for static content](http://www.galcho.com/Blog/post/2008/02/27/IIS7-How-to-set-cache-control-for-static-content.aspx).

Some great info here on [TechNet around how IIS6 handles file caching](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/41cb7f00-21a8-4495-ac09-97590ea431e7.mspx?mfr=true).